# using temp variable to add node to end of linked list in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I am learning about linked lists and I have the following code but I do not understand it. What I am trying to grasp is the concept of how to use a temp variable to add a node to the end of a linked list. Could someone enlighten me as to what is happening?

I understand the first half but logic of the second half confuses me.

```
struct Node{
int data;
Node *next;
};

Node *head = NULL;
head = new Node;
head->next = NULL;
head->data = 97; // I understand up to here
Node *temp = head; //I do not understand this part on
temp->next = new Node;
temp = temp->next;
temp->next=NULL;
temp->data=50;
```

Comment: It helps a lot if you read the code and at the same time draw a sketch with all variables, pointers, and `new` blocks.

Comment: @DYZ so, if you'd be willing, what would a sketch of this particular example look like? I think that would really help me out. I tried to draw one myself but I got stuck on line 5.

Comment: On line 5, draw a new variable box named `temp` with an arrow pointing to the existing variable `head`.

Comment: It's just a confusing piece of code. Nevertheless it's important to understand that 'head' and 'temp' are pointers to nodes. When you re-assign a pointer, the node it points to doesn't change. Drawing a picture will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node *temp = head
```

temp is now equal to head

```
temp->next = new Node;
```

intialize the next node

```
temp = temp->next;
```

now temp is moved to next node

```
temp->next=NULL;
```

this just means the last element of the linked list is just null

```
temp->data=50;
```

this is the value we need to append